# why the button will only change the object properties after the input is manually changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Attached is full code of the application.
The problem is that the buttons of the session length section will only change the CLOCK.session properties and the #countdown span if the session length input is changed first. What is strange is that this code worked before I started to do CSS styling to the page, but no it doesn't (and there should't be any connection).
Thank you for the help!`

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#timer-circle');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const CLOCK = {
 timerInit: function() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.strokeStyle = "#527A71";
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.arc(120, 120, 118, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.stroke();
 },
 drawStep: function() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  context.fillStyle = "#505000";
  context.arc(120, 120, 115, Math.PI / 2 - Math.PI * CLOCK.whichSession().timeStep, Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI * CLOCK.whichSession().timeStep);
  context.stroke();
  context.fill();
  document.querySelector('#countdown').innerText = Math.floor(CLOCK.whichSession().timeZero / 60).toString() + ':' + (CLOCK.whichSession().timeZero % 60).toString();
 },
 initCount: function(total) {
  total *= 60
  if(CLOCK.sessionSwitch) {
   CLOCK.session.timeZero = total;
   let localTimeZero = total;
   CLOCK.session.timeStep = (total - localTimeZero) / total;
  }
  else if(!CLOCK.sessionSwitch) {
   CLOCK.breakProp.timeZero = total;
   let localTimeZero = total;
   CLOCK.breakProp.timeStep = (total - localTimeZero) / total;
  }
 },
 clockDisplay: function(total, zero) {
  document.querySelector('#countdown').innerText = total.toString() + ':00';
 },
 timerReset: function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //INITIALIZING FUNCTIONS AND BUTTONS
 },
 whichSession: function() {
  return CLOCK.sessionSwitch ? CLOCK.session : CLOCK.breakProp;
 },
 timerCount: function() {
  if(CLOCK.whichSession().timeStep <= 1) {
   CLOCK.drawStep();
   CLOCK.whichSession().timeZero--;
   CLOCK.whichSession().timeStep = (60 * CLOCK.whichSession().timeTotal - CLOCK.whichSession().timeZero) / (60 * CLOCK.whichSession().timeTotal);
  }
  else if(CLOCK.whichSession().timeStep >= 1) {
   if(CLOCK.sessionSwitch) {
    // INITIALIZING BREAK COUNT
    CLOCK.sessionSwitch = false;
    document.querySelector('#label').innerText = 'Break!';
    CLOCK.timerReset();
    CLOCK.timerInit();
    CLOCK.initCount(CLOCK.breakProp.timeTotal);
   }
   else if(!CLOCK.sessionSwitch) {
    // INITIALIZING SESSION COUNT
    CLOCK.sessionSwitch = true;
    document.querySelector('#label').innerText = 'Session';
    CLOCK.timerReset();
    CLOCK.timerInit();
    CLOCK.initCount(CLOCK.session.timeTotal);
   }
   //reset the circle
   //switch the countdown to the correct time
   CLOCK.drawStep();
   CLOCK.whichSession().timeZero--;
   CLOCK.whichSession().timeStep = (60 * CLOCK.whichSession().timeTotal - CLOCK.whichSession().timeZero) / (60 * CLOCK.whichSession().timeTotal);
  }
 },
 timerSwitch: false,
 sessionSwitch: true,
 session: {
  timeTotal: undefined,
  timeZero: undefined,
  timeStep: undefined
 },
 breakProp: {
  timeTotal: undefined,
  timeZero: undefined,
  timeStep: undefined
 },
 timerInterval: undefined,
};
$(document).ready(function() {
 CLOCK.timerInit()
 CLOCK.clockDisplay(document.querySelector('#session-length input').value);
 CLOCK.session.timeTotal = Number(document.querySelector('#session-length input').value)
 CLOCK.breakProp.timeTotal = Number(document.querySelector('#break-length input').value)
 $('button.increase').click(function() {
  if($(this)['0'].nextElementSibling.value >= 1 && $(this)['0'].nextElementSibling.value < 99) {
   if(this.parentNode.id == 'session-length') {
    $(this)['0'].nextElementSibling.value++;
    CLOCK.session.timeTotal++;
    CLOCK.clockDisplay($(this)[0].nextElementSibling.value);
   }
   else if(this.parentNode.id = 'break-length') {
    $(this)['0'].nextElementSibling.value++;
    CLOCK.breakProp.timeTotal++;
   }
  }
 });
 $('button.decrease').click(function() {
  if($(this)['0'].previousElementSibling.value > 1 && $(this)['0'].previousElementSibling.value <= 99) {
   $(this)['0'].previousElementSibling.value--;
   if(this.parentNode.id == 'session-length') {
    CLOCK.session.timeTotal--;
    CLOCK.clockDisplay($(this)[0].previousElementSibling.value);
   }
   else if(this.parentNode.id = 'break-length') {
    CLOCK.breakProp.timeTotal--;
   }
  }
 });
 $('input').on('keyup', function() {
  if(this.parentNode.id = 'session-length') {
   CLOCK.session.timeTotal = Number(this.value);
   CLOCK.clockDisplay(this.value);
  }
  else if(this.parentNode.id = 'break-length') {
   CLOCK.breakProp.timeTotal = Number(this.value);
  }
 });
 $('#timer-count').on('click', function() {
  if(!CLOCK.timerSwitch) {
   CLOCK.initCount(CLOCK.session.timeTotal);
   CLOCK.timerInterval = setInterval(CLOCK.timerCount, 1000);
   CLOCK.timerSwitch = true;
   $('button, input').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else if(CLOCK.timerSwitch) {
   clearInterval(CLOCK.timerInterval);
   CLOCK.timerSwitch = false;
   CLOCK.sessionSwitch = true;
   CLOCK.clockDisplay(CLOCK.session.timeTotal, )
   CLOCK.timerReset();
   CLOCK.timerInit();
   $('button, input').prop('disabled', false);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(38, 36, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(81, 66, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(38, 36, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(81, 66, 0, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(38, 36, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(81, 66, 0, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#514200', GradientType=1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: white;
}

#clock-container {
  margin: 100px 20% 0 35%;
  color: white;
}

input {
  width: 65px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  border: solid 7px green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.clock-form {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.decrease {
  margin-left: 0px;
}


#animation {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 7%;
}

#timer-count {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 80px 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#timer-circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alon's Pomodoro Clock</title>
    <!-- =========JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ==============>BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <!-- ============>FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ================>STYLESHEET -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="clock-container">
      <h1>Alon's Pomodoro Clock</h1>
      <div id="session-length" class="input">
        <h3>Session Length</h3>
        <div class="clock-form">
          <button class="increase">+</button>
          <input type="text" maxlength="2" value="25" />
          <button class="decrease">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="break-length" class="input">
        <h3>Break Length</h3>
        <div class="clock-form">
          <button class="increase">+</button>
          <input type="text" maxlength="2" value="5" />
          <button class="decrease">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="animation">
        <canvas id="timer-circle" width="240" height="240">
        </canvas>
        <div id="timer-count">
          <span id="label">Session</span>
          <span id="countdown">01:00</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: I click on `.timer-count` and it begins with a slight delay.

Comment: It is another bug, that I will take care of. However the bug that I am concerned is that the plus and minus buttons will only affect the time in `#countdown` after the input has been manually change, and will not work otherwise

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
problem was that I added a div with class `.clock-form` while editing the css, therefore `$(this)['0'].parentNode.id` refered to `.clock-form` instead of either `session-input` or `break-input`. though I still haven't figured out why the buttons worked after inserting a value to the inputs manually.